# Css doesn't apply on a button

Tags: css

I want to apply a yellow color to a button on my page, but when I call the class, it didn't apply on it and when I inspect the element on the site, it doesn't show the class I'm calling.
The `html` code:

```
<a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %} class="btn btn-warning pull-right">
        {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr" %} Couches en attente {% else %} Layers in stand-by {% endif %}</a>
```

and here is the `CSS`:

```
.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff8f31;
  border-color: #ff8118;
}
.btn-warning:focus,
.btn-warning.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fd7300;
  border-color: #974500;
}
.btn-warning:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fd7300;
  border-color: #d96300;
}
.btn-warning:active,
.btn-warning.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fd7300;
  border-color: #d96300;
}
```

and the view on the button:
[image]

Comment: Your basic code as shown appears to work fine (href mistake fixed), assuming that color is what you call “yellow” - https://jsfiddle.net/jufxskvw/ So what you have shown us so far, does not seem to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [mre] that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close properly the a href="" :)

your code:

```
<a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %} class="btn btn-warning pull-right">
```

working code:

```
<a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %}" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">
```

Comment: href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %}" <- last " is missing

Comment: I am not sure if that cause the issue, cause I copied and paste code above and it works, for me. So yeah the `href` should be closed but not sure if that is the issue